# Used Ford Fiesta Rusty Sills

Tags: ford, corrosion, used

looking for some advice as to whether the picture shown is something serious to worry about when buying a used Ford Fiesta. It’s 11 years old and doesn’t have any corrosion advisories on MOT history apart from coils and brake pipes a couple years ago, all of which are replaced. The sills look the same on both sides of the car. Hard to say if underneath is much more damage or if the rest of the car is clean. Sadly I’ve already paid a deposit, not sure if it’s worth walking away at this stage  [image]

Comment: If it looks the same on both sides, probably more rust to be had. Yea, should've looked underneath before putting down deposit. Where's the car?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! In most cases with rust on body panels is, whatever you can see, multiply that times 10 and you're probably pretty close to the amount of rust present. I'm not sure, but it *looks* as though there are some rust bubbles under the paint up the rocker just a little bit in your picture. If it's rusting through from the back side of the paint, you can be positive there's a lot more which is hiding. From what I know of MOTs, homey don't play the rust through game. You'd be required to get this fixed prior to passing (if my thinking is correct).

Comment: There will be no declarative answer to "looking for some advice." It'll all be opinion, which is off-topic. I voted to close.